# Javascript get number of files having different id's from file input element without multiple attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple input files having different ID's. I would like to count the number of files and get the names of files.

```html
<div class="fieldContainer"><input type="file" class="txtField"  name="fileAttach[]" id="filename1"></div>
<div class="fieldContainer"><input type="file" class="txtField"  name="fileAttach[]" id="filename2" ></div>
<div class="fieldContainer"><input type="file" class="txtField"  name="fileAttach[]" id="filename3" ></div>
```

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: Is my answer useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using querySelectorAll API by passing required selectors.
Please find the jsfiddle

```
var count = document.querySelectorAll(".fieldContainer > input[type='file']")
alert(count.length);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/smv3b53w/

Comment: Thanks Jain. It helps alot.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your request correctly, you can use a little bit of jQuery here to count each file and increment a variable.

```
var i = 0; //variable to count each file - starting at 0
$('input[type="file"]').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id')); //alerts for each file found
  i++; // adds 1 to the variable "i"
});
alert("there are "+i+" files."); // alerts the final count of variable "i" - giving you the total number of files
```

see fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mgtyxusm/1/

Answer (score 0):

When `input` selected file, add name of file to an object and then write content of object in html.

```js
var files = {};
$("input").on("change", function(e){ 
   var count = 0; 
   var id = $(this).prop("id");
   files[id] = $(this)[0].files[0].name;
 
   $("ol").html("");
   $.each(files, function(key, value){
       $("ol").append("<li>"+ value +"</li>");
       count++;
   });
   $("#count").text(count + " Items selected");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="file" id="filename1" />
<div>
    <input type="file" id="filename2" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="file" id="filename3" />
</div>
<div id="count"></div>
<ol></ol>
```